# To many WooCommmerce related transients in WordPress options table

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql, options, table

I have the following problem on my Wordpress installation. There are too many, hundreds to thousands of transients in the options table. And the options table grows and grows and grows. If I don't manually delete the transients from the table, the hosting provider shuts down my website because it causes too much traffic. I have deactivated all plugins except Woocommerce and Stripe Gateway. Unfortunately it didn't help. Does anyone have an idea why the options table is so bloated? Thank you for your answers.

I deactivated all unnecessary plugins without success. I tried all the tools under woocommerce status tools without success. I tried to optimize the database tables every day with plugins, without success.

here are the most frequently occurring transients in the options table

```
_transient_timeout_wc_child_has_weight_5387
_transient_wc_child_has_weight_5387
_transient_timeout_wc_child_has_dimensions_5387
_transient_wc_child_has_dimensions_5387
```

Comment: Transients are part of working with WordPress. They're used to store temporary data. If you're concerned that WooCommerce has too many, you'll need to take it up with their support team.

Comment: There is a "Delete Expired Transients" plugin, which deletes expired transients every day. Its description says the reason of possibly having too many transients:
"because old transients are only deleted when requested again after they’ve expired, many transients stay in the database". So it would worth trying out that plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/delete-expired-transients/

Comment: There may also be something about your host that's preventing WC from running it's self cleaning functions.  You may want to migrate to a host that is specifically designed for running WP and WooCommerce.